# Visual Studio Code Coverage includes unwanted libraries

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, c++-cli, code-coverage

I have a question about unit testing code coverage when using C++/CLI.

I have managed to get code coverage working in visual studio IDE, and also from the command line using `vsinstr` and `vsperfmon`. However the problem I am facing now is that the code coverage includes functions from `std` library, `boost` and other libraries that I don't want to get code coverage for.

I have tried the `/EXCLUDE` option, but it doesn't work at all.

I have the following two `.rsp` files:

```
/coverage
/exclude:std::*
/exclude:boost::*
MyExe.exe

/coverage
/exclude:std::*
/exclude:boost::*
UnitTestsDll.dll
```

I am using the following command to instrument the `.exe` and unit test dll:

```
vsinstr @foo.rsp
```

And then starting the performance monitor:

```
Start vsperfmon -coverage -output:mytestrun.coverage
```

After that I run my unit tests from the visual studio IDE, and when they finish I shut down the `vsperfcmd`.

When I then view `mytestrun.coverage` in visual studio, it still has all the `std` and other libraries.

Am I missing something important?

Hope someone can help.

EDIT:

I have tried the following command to exclude the unit tests from the coverage:
vsinstr -coverage "UnitTestsDll.dll" /EXCLUDE:UnitTestsNameSpace.*

Notice that instead of using `::` I am using the `.`, because the unit test namespace is a managed one. After running the code coverage and checking it, it seems to have got rid of the coverage for the unit tests, which is the correct behaviour. So it seems that the `/EXCLUDE` works on the `.` separator, and doesn't on the `::` separator.